# How to skip typing in textboxes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, keyboard-events

I want to extend a class from TextBox component of C# and override an "On[Event]" method in order to check the input of typing in text box and skip some keys to be entered in the text box. I'm search for something like this (the following code is not the solution!):

```
    public class NumText : TextBox
    {
         protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
         {
              if (e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57)
                  base.OnKeyDown(e);
         }
    }
```

Comment: This depends on the UI framework you use (WPF, Silverlight, WinForms,...) and sometimes it's version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just don't override the Event ,add a new Event instead if you need to prevent several Key's being pressed .

```
this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this_onKeyPress);

private void this_onKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [KeyEventArgs.Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled.aspx) Property.

Quote to MSDN article :

> true to bypass the control's default handling; otherwise, false to
>   also pass the event along to the default control handler.